# How to go about calling a javascript based form for external site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I apologize for the title, I'm not quite sure how to word my question with brevity.

Say I make a form in knockout.js and someone else wants to use it. Instead of copying the knockout.js source file, the javascript containing the viewmodel and even the html for the form, is it possible to use use javascript (or something else) to call my server which would then return all of the necessary code? I guess what I'm asking is can I host these files, and to make it simple on their side, just have a few lines to call the necessary files to use the knockout form?

I've noticed a lot of sites have features that call into their API via javascript and then something gets returned (seemingly), such as Twitter and facebook.

How about twitter for example?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com" data-text="Test Tweet">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Is this line `js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` simply including the javascript file from Twitter's servers necessary for a tweet button and the rest of the code just ties into their API to let it know what to return?

Is it similar to using google for jQuery?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

**edit - I see this is dealing with same origin policy. How can my server load jQuery.js when it's hosted on google's server and not mine?**

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you can't because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents you from calling JavaScript from another domain.

However, you can set up [CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) to allow sharing scripts.  If you visit that CORS link you can learn about setting it up - the method depends on your web server software.  Setting this up (per file) allows the file to be shared to specified (or all) domains.

Comment: Does this mean CORS is used when google is used to host jQuery or even fonts for that matter? How about twitter? [This link](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) is javascript on the Twitter servers which is referenced for a tweet button.

Comment: I believe that's right, at least for JavaScript.  If you look at the headers, for instance for [jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js), you'll see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header - that's CORS in action.  Flash uses a different mechanism for sharing.  Fonts probably don't use anything at all - there's not a lot of security risk for sharing Comic Sans between servers.  I could be wrong about that, never given it any thought.